# ASP.NET MVC - Regex to allow less than character safely

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 app where my business users require to enter a `<` (less than sign). For their specific business segment the `<` is a common used sign. I know about the problem of XSS-Attacks, but I'm trying to find a solution to allow just the `<` without opening XSS-Attacks. I **DON'T** want to allow HTML, so I don't what to set `[AllowHtml]` or disable the validation rules. They should be turned on.

I thought about to only allow the `<` **followed by** a space, which isn't a valid html tag and isn't detected by ASP.NET as dangerous request. I assume that the best option would be to setup a regex, but I don't know how the regex should look like.

For example I want to extend this regex (Data annotation): `[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$", ErrorMessage = "some message")]` to allow `<` **followed by** a space.

Is there also anything to consider if I would allow `<` (followed by space)?

Comment: You might repeat 1 or more times matching the characters that you already have, or match a `< ` using an alternation `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]|< )+$` I don't know if there is an XSS vulnarability so you would have to do some research and if possible write some tests. Perhaps [this page](https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet) can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]|<(?= ))+$", ErrorMessage = "some message")]
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` - a letter or digit or space
  - `|` - or
  - `<(?= )` - a `<` that is followed with a space
- `)+` - end of group, match one or more times
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SVPVdd/1).

Comment: Thank you. It is not related to the original question, but maybe you can help me also. If I would like to add also newline & carriage returns, can i use this one: `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]|<(?= )|(\n|\r|\r\n))+$` ?

Comment: @Phoniex If you want to match multiline strings, you may use `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s]|<(?=\s))+$`